# Java: Write to and read from same process multiple times

Tags: java, process

I've gone through so many related StackOverflow questions for this that I'm getting lost in them, and I've coded this multiple ways, but none seem to solve this problem in a way that works for me: **How can I send output to the same command and process multiple times while at the same time receiving input from this same process?**
(See [Input various strings to same process in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353977/input-various-strings-to-same-process-in-java) for a similar question, but this ended with only a theoretical answer.)
The command (command line, from a C++ executable) loads a large file, and then I want to send input to it very quickly, get back the answer, do other stuff in between, then send different input and get the corresponding answer. Multiply this by thousands or millions of times.

One implementation, with threads:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" "));
kenLMProcess = pb.start();
KenLMInThread lmInput = new KenLMInThread(kenLMProcess.getInputStream());
KenLMInThread lmError = new KenLMInThread(kenLMProcess.getErrorStream());
KenLMOutThread lmOutput = new KenLMOutThread(kenLMProcess.getOutputStream());
lmOutput.inStr = "Test . \n";
lmInput.start();
lmOutput.start();
lmError.start();
lmOutput.join();
lmInput.join();
lmError.join();
outStr = lmInput.newStr;
```

But join waits until the thread ends. What if I don't want to wait for it to end? I can't seem to figure out how to use wait() for that purpose. For one I'd prefer to not have to keep opening and closing a new output stream and input stream every time I query the command. But at least that's better than starting a new ProcessBuilder every time.

Here's what run() looks like for KenLMOutThread:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        pw.write(inStr+"\n");
        pw.write('\n');
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while inputting to KenLM.");

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        pw.flush();
        try {
            pw.flush();
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Supposedly flush is supposed to let it move on, and "\n" at the end is supposed to help, but it just hangs unless I use close. And if I use close, I can't use the OutputStream anymore. I'm also then unable to make a new OutputStream from the Process.

If it helps, here's a more simple implementation with everything together (taken from [How to send EOF to a process in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773158/how-to-send-eof-to-a-process-in-java)):
Note that close() is used, and using flush() without close() causes the program to hang.

```
public static String pipe(String str, String command2) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command2);
    OutputStream out = p2.getOutputStream();
    out.write(str.getBytes());
    out.close();
    p2.waitFor();
    BufferedReader reader
            = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Other things I've tried:

- Using exec(): Process kenLMProcess=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
- Putting the command process in its own thread: KenLMProcessThread procThread = new KenLMProcessThread(pb.start());

Answer (score 0):

If the target process is hanging unless you close the output stream, the problem is at that end: it is reading until end of stream before doing anything. Nothing you can do about that at the sending end.

Comment: The command does output before finishing taking in input though (I should have mentioned this). I tested this by having it read in a very large file. It outputs along the way (it only processes one line at a time).

Comment: In essence, my question can be simplified to (at least I hope): How can I write to a process, do something else, and then write to it again? Surely that's possible?